# Как внутри файла передать переменную из одного блока в другой?

Tags: php, html

Здравствуйте.

Я начинающий, так что не судите строго.

Подскажите, как решить такую задачку: файл состоит из двух блоков - 1 блок выводит список заметок, 2 блок выводит текст выбранной заметки. Посетитель страницы выбирает нужную ему заметку и нажимает ссылку. Переменная ссылки должна направиться во второй блок, где формируется запрос к базе данных на вывод текста заметки.

Нужно, чтобы посетитель, находясь на странице, мог одновременно видеть и выбирать заметку и на этой же странице ее читать.
Подскажите, где можно получить информацию или скрипт по данному вопросу.

```
<?php

    include("blocks/bd.php");

    if(isset ($_GET['cat']))   {$cat = $_GET['cat'];}

?>

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>

<head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1251">
<title>Главная</title>

<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<script src="js/jquery-1.5.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="js/equalHeight.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</head>

<body>

     <!--блок каркаса сайта-->
    <div id="framework">
        <!--блок заголовка-->
        <?php include("blocks/header.php"); ?>
        <!--блок навигации-->
        <?php include("blocks/novig.php"); ?>

<!--блок блок вывода списка заметок-->

        <div id="min_content">

        <h2>СПИСОК ЗАМЕТОК</h2>

            <?php

$result = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM data WHERE cat='$cat',$db);

    if (!$result)

    {echo "<p>Запрос на выборку из БД не прошел. Напишите об этом администратору
     erpase@rambler.ru.<br><strong>Код ошибки: </strong></p>"; exit (mysql_error ());}

    if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {$myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result);

do {printf ("<div id='administracia_post'>

            <p class='post_title'>Номер заметки: <span>%s</span></p>

            <p class='post_title2'>Заметка про:<br> <span>%s</span></p>

            <p class='post_title'>Автор заметки: <span>%s</span></p>

            <p class='post_title'>Дата публикации: <span>%s</span></p>

            <p class='post_title'>Количество просмотров: <span>%s</span></p>

 **<p><a href='view_post.php?id=%s'><img class='button' src='%s'></a></p>**

</div>", $myrow['id'], $myrow['title'], $myrow['author'], $myrow['date'], $myrow['view'], $myrow['id'], $myrow['button']);  }

while ($myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result));   }   }

else {echo "<p>Информация по запросу не может быть извлечена в БД нет записей.</p>"; exit ();}

            ?>

        </div>

<!--блок вывода текста заметки-->

        <div id="content">

<!--как передать в этот блок переменную из первого блока-->
        <?php

        $result2 = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM data WHERE id='$id'",$db);

    if (!$result2)

    {echo "<p>Запрос на выборку из БД не прошел. Напишите об этом администратору
     erpase@rambler.ru.<br><strong>Код ошибки: </strong></p>"; exit (mysql_error ());}

    if (mysql_num_rows($result2) > 0) {$myrow2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2);

do {printf ("<div id='administracia_post2'>

            <p class='post_title3'>%s</p>

            <p class='post_title'>Номер заметки: <span>%s</span></p>

            <p class='post_title'>Автор заметки: <span>%s</span></p>

            <p class='post_title'>Дата публикации: <span>%s</span></p>

            <p class='post_text'>%s</p></p>

</div>",$myrow2['title'], $myrow2['id'], $myrow2['author'], $myrow2['date'], $myrow2['text']);}

while ($myrow2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2));   }

else {echo "<p>Информация по запросу не может быть извлечена в БД нет записей.</p>"; exit ();}

        ?>

        </div>

        <!--блок выравнивания полей-->

        <?php include("blocks/clear.php"); ?>

    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Покажите ваш код, а то немного не ясно что имеется в виду под блоками.

Answer (score 1):

У вас какой-то неправильный подход. Один запрос к php - один результат в виде HTML, если сказать по-простому. Если я правильно понял вашу задачу, то мне известно три варианта её решения.
1) С помощью фреймов - на данный момент **устаревший вариант**.
2) С помощью CSS. Делаем общий запрос к php, и выводим на страницу все записи, скрываем все кроме одной. На JS пишем скрипт, который при наведении мышки на ссылку или при клике на неё делает одну запись невидимой, а нужную видимой. Это какой-то **неправильный вариант**, хотя и рабочий.
3) С помощью подхода AJAX. Делаем асинхронный запрос к PHP скрипту, передаём необходимые параметры(например, идентификатор статьи в БД) с помощью GET или POST запроса. Динамически обновляем необходимую нам область страницы без перезагрузки. Это **рекомендуемый мною вариант**. Но здесь надо быть осторожным. Я, например, отказался от такого способа навигации. Так как есть проблемы, например, с не работающей кнопкой "назад", с несохранением переходов в Истории, при SEO оптимизации и т.д.

Comment: Ну проблемы в п.3 решаются, вопрос в желании этим заниматься... А так +1.

Answer (score 0):

Всё очень просто! Для этого будем использовать GET запрос.

```
<?php
    /* Здесь запрос в базу, на получение списка заметок */

    // Выводим список заметок 
   echo '<div class="list">';
      while ($row = $res->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        echo '<a href="?z='.$row["id"].'">Я заметка</a>';
      }
   echo '</div>';

    //Если существует z и является числом
    if(isset($_GET['z']) && ctype_digit($_GET['z'])){

    /* Здесь подаётся запрос в базу на получение текста заметки с идентификатором z */

      //Блок куда выводится текст заметки
     echo '<div class="content">'

     echo '</div>';

    }
?>
```